# Outlook addin not showing on Mac

Tags: macos, outlook-addin

For Outlook on Mac, on every Outlook startup, my add-in disappears, even though it is visible on OWA. To make the add-ins visible again, i go to managed add-ins in OWA and turn them off and on again. They immediately appear on Outlook, but they disappear again at the next startup.

This issue started a few weeks ago and works fine on windows. 
Does anyone have any suggestions on how to fix this or why is this happening?

Comment: Thanks for raising it. what is the build version you are seeing this behaviour? How many number of add-ins were installed?And can you try waiting for some time (or) try switching b/w mails and see if they are showing up?

Comment: Outlook version 16.13.1 (180523). I have 3 add-ins installed and my coworkers have only one and they are experiencing the same issue. I've tried waiting quite a while but they never appeared. I've tried switching between accounts and this seems to make the add-ins show, but as soon as i restart Outlook, all the add-ins are hidden again.

Comment: @TudorIordan were you able to solve this issue ?

Answer (score 3):

You need to allow Optional Connected Experience in your Privacy Preferences.
Restart Outlook. It should work now.

[image]

Comment: You can add your image inline, please follow instructions here: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/344853/3519504

Answer (score 0):

I am using office 365 for business (I think it's the enterprise edition). We have some add-ins automatically deployed by the admins to all users, and users can choose whether to install some additional ones.

My pain was that I couldn't use Jira for Outlook on mac (add-in worked fine in iPhone, windows client and web).

I needed to do two things to enable the add-ins in outlook for mac. I had to quit any office application, not just outlook for the below to function.

1. As mentioned in another answer, you need to enable the "optional connected experiences" from Preferences -> Privacy. This will enable the store icon to appear again after you restart outlook, but add-ins were still unusable for me.
2. After I quit the application, I reset my outlook preferences with the OutlookResetPreferences tool, downloaded from [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook/troubleshoot/outlook-for-mac/useful-tools).

Voila, add-ins reappeared (both admin and user managed).